# Is there a NuGet package for NUnit that includes the syntax helpers?

Tags: .net, nunit, nuget

The regular NUnit package is pretty much stripped down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the NUnit Assert syntax helpers are in the NUnit.Framework assembly as of version 2.5. This assembly is included in the NUnit NuGet package.

Make sure you add `using NUnit.Framework;`

Anyway, if this isn't the answer you're looking for, perhaps you can clarify the question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. It has not only moved into the NUnit.Framework assembly, but also into that namespace. I was looking for it in the SyntaxHelper namespace. Thanks.

Comment: If you're picking up a legacy project, Keep "using NUnit.Framework;" but remove "using NUnit.Framework.SyntaxHelpers;"

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the NUnit NuGet package and it has 4MB of stuff in the packages folder - are you sure what you're looking for isn't included?

One of the things that annoyed me about NUnit's package was that so much was included - I only wanted the required DLLs to create test projects! :(